# Output all rows that are linked to the same keyword

Tags: python, pandas

Ive currently a DataFrame[1]  and i want an output[2] that meets my requierements. What i did so far was searching for the specific keywords and output the new DataFrame. But now i have also an additional search criteria 'avgSalience'.

Doing queries like below results as expected in rows that only contains the specific keyword, but what i want to do is searching for specific keywords and see if they have a certain avgSalience, if yes i would like to output those words and every word that is linked to the same url. You can see in the DataFrame that multiple words are linked to the same url.

```
df=df[df['name'].str.lower().str.contains('google|facebook')]
df=df[df['avgSalience']>0.01]
```

[1]

```
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| url                  | date       | word                    | mentioned | avgSalience       |
|----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| newspaperarticle.com | 2018-12-22 |  canada                 | 1         | 1.2               |
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 |  facebook               | 2         | 0.7               |
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 |  bad                    | 3         | 1.1               |
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 |  strong                 | 1         | 0.5               |
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------------
```

[2] desired output if i want facebook keyword to have atleast an avgSalience of >0.5

```
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| url                  | date       | word                    | mentioned | avgSalience       |
|----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------------+
| 
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 |  facebook               | 2         | 0.7               |
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 |  bad                    | 3         | 1.1               |
| articleUSA.com       | 2018-12-23 |  strong                 | 1         | 0.5               |
+----------------------+------------+-------------------------+-----------+-------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sorry I misread your question. I think you can get the unique url values from the first dataframe and then use `isin` method, perhaps something like this. But I haven't tested the code yet.

```
url_values = df[(df['name'].str.lower().str.contains('google|facebook')) & (df['avgSalience']>0.01)].url.unique()

df=df[df.url.isin(url_values)]
```